# How can I paste something to the VIM from the clipboard

Tags: debian, vim

How can I paste something into Vim from the clipboard?

In Windows, `"*p` works as expected but in Debian, both `"*p` and `"+p` don't work with both `clipboard=unnamed` and `clipboard=unnamedplus`.

Comment: vim in a terminal or a gtk-enabled graphical vim?

Comment: terminal ("echo $TERM" gives me "xterm")

Comment: You probably didn't compile vim with X clipboard support. What does `:version` say?

Comment: Yep, there's the problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Debian, if you want X clipboard support, install the `vim-gtk` (or `vim-gnome` for Gnome specific extras) package *instead* of the standard `vim` package. `vim` will run normally in the terminal, it is only when it is invoked as `gvim` that the GUI is started.

Answer (score 3):

In a terminal

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> (paste)
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> (copy)

In an xterm I get into insert mode, highlight what I want to copy, then use the middle button, (to trigger paste), ensuring I click where I want highlighted pasted.

[How does copy-paste work with xterm? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/237942/how-does-copy-paste-work-with-xterm)